# text/css loaded as textplain aws

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When I update/load a css from AWS S3-Cloudfront the "content-type" attribute defaults to text/plain attribute.

So, even though I specify:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/test.css"/>
```

...the HTML errors out the css file.

Example: quantprice.com/test.html

BTW, I'm on Ubuntu, so to synch, I use the cmd:

```
s3cmd sync --delete-removed <dir1> <dir2>
```

Each time I load/update a css file, I've to manually change the attribute in the s3 bucket for each css file after I sync.

How do I avoid this manual work?